# Add unique identifier column to a nested list of data frames

Tags: r, dataframe, nested-lists, uniqueidentifier, mapply

#### Example Data

I am working with a nested list of data frames. My list contains over 1,000 lists, each containing a single data frame as their only element. Each data frame contains 30+ observations of 10+ variables. To keep things simple, here is a small example list:

```
df1 <- tibble::tibble(a = 1:25, b = 1:25, c = 1:25, d = 1:25, e = 1:25)
df2 <- tibble::tibble(a = 1:35, b = 1:35, c = 1:35, d = 1:35, e = 1:35)
df3 <- tibble::tibble(a = 1:30, b = 1:30, c = 1:30, d = 1:30, e = 1:30)
df4 <- tibble::tibble(a = 1:20, b = 1:20, c = 1:20, d = 1:20, e = 1:20)

dfs_list <- list(list(a = df1), list(a = df2), list(a = df3), list(a = df4))
  dfs_list

[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
# A tibble: 25 x 5
       a     b     c     d     e
   <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
 1     1     1     1     1     1
 2     2     2     2     2     2
 3     3     3     3     3     3
 4     4     4     4     4     4
 5     5     5     5     5     5
 6     6     6     6     6     6
 7     7     7     7     7     7
 8     8     8     8     8     8
 9     9     9     9     9     9
10    10    10    10    10    10
# ... with 15 more rows


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
# A tibble: 35 x 5
       a     b     c     d     e
   <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
 1     1     1     1     1     1
 2     2     2     2     2     2
 3     3     3     3     3     3
 4     4     4     4     4     4
 5     5     5     5     5     5
 6     6     6     6     6     6
 7     7     7     7     7     7
 8     8     8     8     8     8
 9     9     9     9     9     9
10    10    10    10    10    10
# ... with 25 more rows


[[3]]
[[3]][[1]]
# A tibble: 30 x 5
       a     b     c     d     e
   <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
 1     1     1     1     1     1
 2     2     2     2     2     2
 3     3     3     3     3     3
 4     4     4     4     4     4
 5     5     5     5     5     5
 6     6     6     6     6     6
 7     7     7     7     7     7
 8     8     8     8     8     8
 9     9     9     9     9     9
10    10    10    10    10    10
# ... with 20 more rows


[[4]]
[[4]][[1]]
# A tibble: 20 x 5
       a     b     c     d     e
   <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
 1     1     1     1     1     1
 2     2     2     2     2     2
 3     3     3     3     3     3
 4     4     4     4     4     4
 5     5     5     5     5     5
 6     6     6     6     6     6
 7     7     7     7     7     7
 8     8     8     8     8     8
 9     9     9     9     9     9
10    10    10    10    10    10
# ... with 10 more rows
```

---

#### Desired Output

I'm trying to generate a column containing a unique identifier for each data frame in my list. The column would be based on two sequences of numbers; say, `1:10` and `1:100`. For example, the column in the first data frame would contain *1.1*, the second would contain *2.1*, and so on, all the way up to *10.100*.

Working off the smaller example from the beginning, let's make my number sequences `1:2` and `1:2`. The `identifier` column below is what I'm looking to add to each data frame in my list:

```
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
# A tibble: 25 x 6
       a     b     c     d     e identifier
   <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <chr>     
 1     1     1     1     1     1 1.1       
 2     2     2     2     2     2 1.1       
 3     3     3     3     3     3 1.1       
 4     4     4     4     4     4 1.1       
 5     5     5     5     5     5 1.1       
 6     6     6     6     6     6 1.1       
 7     7     7     7     7     7 1.1       
 8     8     8     8     8     8 1.1       
 9     9     9     9     9     9 1.1       
10    10    10    10    10    10 1.1       
# ... with 15 more rows


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
# A tibble: 35 x 6
       a     b     c     d     e identifier
   <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <chr>     
 1     1     1     1     1     1 2.1      
 2     2     2     2     2     2 2.1       
 3     3     3     3     3     3 2.1       
 4     4     4     4     4     4 2.1       
 5     5     5     5     5     5 2.1       
 6     6     6     6     6     6 2.1       
 7     7     7     7     7     7 2.1       
 8     8     8     8     8     8 2.1       
 9     9     9     9     9     9 2.1       
10    10    10    10    10    10 2.1       
# ... with 25 more rows


[[3]]
[[3]][[1]]
# A tibble: 30 x 6
       a     b     c     d     e identifier
   <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <chr>     
 1     1     1     1     1     1 1.2       
 2     2     2     2     2     2 1.2       
 3     3     3     3     3     3 1.2       
 4     4     4     4     4     4 1.2       
 5     5     5     5     5     5 1.2       
 6     6     6     6     6     6 1.2       
 7     7     7     7     7     7 1.2       
 8     8     8     8     8     8 1.2       
 9     9     9     9     9     9 1.2       
10    10    10    10    10    10 1.2       
# ... with 20 more rows


[[4]]
[[4]][[1]]
# A tibble: 20 x 5
       a     b     c     d     e identifier
   <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <chr>     
 1     1     1     1     1     1 2.2       
 2     2     2     2     2     2 2.2       
 3     3     3     3     3     3 2.2       
 4     4     4     4     4     4 2.2       
 5     5     5     5     5     5 2.2       
 6     6     6     6     6     6 2.2       
 7     7     7     7     7     7 2.2       
 8     8     8     8     8     8 2.2       
 9     9     9     9     9     9 2.2       
10    10    10    10    10    10 2.2       
# ... with 10 more rows
```

---

#### Attempted Methods

I've tried creating an array using `apply(expand.grid())`, then binding one observation of the array to each data frame using `mapply()` :

```
a.b <- apply(expand.grid(c(1:2), c(1:2)), 1, paste, collapse = '.')
mapply(cbind, dfs_list, "Identifier" = a.b, SIMPLIFY = F)
```

However, the column is inserted to the parent list, instead of directly to the data frames:

```
[[1]]
               Identifier    
[1,] tbl_df,5 "1.1"

[[2]]
               Identifier    
[1,] tbl_df,5 "2.1"

[[3]]
               Identifier    
[1,] tbl_df,5 "1.2"

[[4]]
               Identifier    
[1,] tbl_df,5 "2.2"
```

---

After some trial and error, I attempted a slightly different approach later in the evening. At first I thought I'd solved my problem, but the list generated was 13 GB as opposed to 19 MB before, and took (relatively) much, much longer to write, so I doubt this is the solution. I'm also unable to reproduce my results using my example data set this morning.

```
> dfs_identify <- dfs_list %>% 
+   apply(function(z) mapply(cbind, z, "Identifier" = a.b, SIMPLIFY = F))
Error in match.fun(FUN) : argument "FUN" is missing, with no default
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Map(`names<-`, dfs_list, a.b)
```

This gives each list item the name you made.  It doesn't say "Identifier", but I think this is what you are after.

Edit:

```
Map(function(x, y) list(cbind(x[[1]], "Identifier" = y)), dfs_list, a.b)
```

This gives a new column of identifiers.  x[[1]] is to get inside the nested structure, and list() re-creates the original nesting structure.  Map is the same as mapply(..., simplify = FALSE)

Answer (score 2):

You may try this approach with `lapply` and `Map` -

```
result <- lapply(seq_along(dfs_list), function(x) {
  Map(cbind, dfs_list[[x]], 
             Identifier = paste(x, seq_along(dfs_list[[x]]), sep = '.'))
})

result

#[[1]]
#[[1]][[1]]
#                   mpg cyl disp  hp drat Identifier
#Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90        1.1
#Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90        1.1
#Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85        1.1
#Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08        1.1
#Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15        1.1

#[[1]][[2]]
#                   mpg cyl disp  hp drat Identifier
#Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90        1.2
#Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85        1.2
#Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08        1.2
#Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15        1.2


#[[2]]
#[[2]][[1]]
#                   mpg cyl disp  hp drat Identifier
#Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90        2.1
#Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90        2.1
#Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85        2.1
#Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08        2.1
#Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15        2.1
```

**data**

It is easier to help if you provide data in a [reproducible format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269)

```
dfs_list <- list(list(mtcars[1:5, 1:5],mtcars[2:5, 1:5]), list(mtcars[1:5, 1:5]))
```

Comment: I've edited my post to include reproducible data, thank you! This is a robust solution to the problem, and I'm sure I'll use it in the future. However, the identifiers generated are not iterating in the way I'd like in my specific scenario - this is because each of my nested lists contain only one data frame each. When I use this method, only the first number continues in sequence, i.e. `1:1`, `2:1`, `3:1`, `4:1`, etc., but I want the second number to change as well, independent/regardless of list locations: for example, `1:1`, `2:1`, `1:2`, `2:2`.